# How to solve database missing issue, when deploying ASP.NET MVC project to Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ef-database-first

I use database first approach in this web app. When I run the project on my local device, it is perfect.

After I publish the web app to Azure, and click the page displayed data, it returns an error page:

[image: after deploy in azure]

Comment: Your question and description provided does not contain enough information. In order to solve issue you have to explain what you are doing for particular action and also that sample code reproduce the issue. Locally working means if something is missing in cloud or it is misconfigured or that component not present at all. There are many cases.

Comment: can you enable error reporting on your published project, or better yet always use logging tools like serilog or log4net so you can check whenever an exception is happing in-depth.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.